# In dynamic country state selection run on java script. How to change default selection for state?

Tags: javascript, php

Good Day, 
This source now allows me to preselect default country. But I need to get preselect default state as well. Can’t figure out how to modify script. Basically I want to tie my PHP code to select box form and for every account to be able to preselect country stage. Help is greatly appreciated.

// ////////////////THIS IS INCLUDED JAVA Script FILE TITLED countries.js ///////////////

```
// Setting Arrays ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    var country_arr = new Array( "USA", "Canada", "United Kingdom");




    // States

var s_a = new Array();
s_a[0]="";
s_a[1]="Alabama|Alaska|Arizona|Arkansas|California|Colorado|Connecticut|Delaware|District of Columbia|Florida|Georgia|Hawaii|Idaho|Illinois|Indiana|Iowa|Kansas|Kentucky|Louisiana|Maine|Maryland|Massachusetts|Michigan|Minnesota|Mississippi|Missouri|Montana|Nebraska|Nevada|New Hampshire|New Jersey|New Mexico|New York|North Carolina|North Dakota|Ohio|Oklahoma|Oregon|Pennsylvania|Rhode Island|South Carolina|South Dakota|Tennessee|Texas|Utah|Vermont|Virginia|Washington|West Virginia|Wisconsin|Wyoming";
s_a[2]="Alberta|British Columbia|Manitoba|New Brunswick|Newfoundland|Northwest Territories|Nova Scotia|Nunavut|Ontario|Prince Edward Island|Quebec|Saskatchewan|Yukon Territory";
s_a[3]="Barking and Dagenham|Barnet|Barnsley|Bath and North East Somerset|Bedfordshire|Bexley|Birmingham|Blackburn with Darwen|Blackpool|Bolton|Bournemouth|Bracknell Forest|Bradford|Brent|Brighton and Hove|Bromley|Buckinghamshire|Bury|Calderdale|Cambridgeshire|Camden|Cheshire|City of Bristol|City of Kingston upon Hull|City of London|Cornwall|Coventry|Croydon|Cumbria|Darlington|Derby|Derbyshire|Devon|Doncaster|Dorset|Dudley|Durham|Ealing|East Riding of Yorkshire|East Sussex|Enfield|Essex|Gateshead|Gloucestershire|Greenwich|Hackney|Halton|Hammersmith and Fulham|Hampshire|Haringey|Harrow|Hartlepool|Havering|Herefordshire|Hertfordshire|Hillingdon|Hounslow|Isle of Wight|Islington|Kensington and Chelsea|Kent|Kingston upon Thames|Kirklees|Knowsley|Lambeth|Lancashire|Leeds|Leicester|Leicestershire|Lewisham|Lincolnshire|Liverpool|Luton|Manchester|Medway|Merton|Middlesbrough|Milton Keynes|Newcastle upon Tyne|Newham|Norfolk|North East Lincolnshire|North Lincolnshire|North Somerset|North Tyneside|North Yorkshire|Northamptonshire|Northumberland|Nottingham|Nottinghamshire|Oldham|Oxfordshire|Peterborough|Plymouth|Poole|Portsmouth|Reading|Redbridge|Redcar and Cleveland|Richmond upon Thames|Rochdale|Rotherham|Rutland|Salford|Sandwell|Sefton|Sheffield|Shropshire|Slough|Solihull|Somerset|South Gloucestershire|South Tyneside|Southampton|Southend-on-Sea|Southwark|St. Helens|Staffordshire|Stockport|Stockton-on-Tees|Stoke-on-Trent|Suffolk|Sunderland|Surrey|Sutton|Swindon|Tameside|Telford and Wrekin|Thurrock|Torbay|Tower Hamlets|Trafford|Wakefield|Walsall|Waltham Forest|Wandsworth|Warrington|Warwickshire|West Berkshire|West Sussex|Westminster|Wigan|Wiltshire|Windsor and Maidenhead|Wirral|Wokingham|Wolverhampton|Worcestershire|York";

// Now Java script ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
function populateStates(countryElementId, stateElementId) {
var selectedCountryIndex = document.getElementById(countryElementId).selectedIndex;
var stateElement = document.getElementById(stateElementId);
stateElement.length = 0; // Fixed by Julian Woods
stateElement.options[0] = new Option('Select State', '0');
stateElement.selectedIndex = 0;

var state_arr = s_a[selectedCountryIndex].split("|");

for (var i = 0; i < state_arr.length; i++) {
stateElement.options[stateElement.length] = new Option(state_arr[i], state_arr[i]);
}
}

function populateCountries(countryElementId, stateElementId, countrySelected) {
var indexSelected=0, countryElement = document.getElementById(countryElementId);
countryElement.length = 0;
countryElement.options[0] = new Option('Select Country', '0');
countryElement.selectedIndex = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < country_arr.length; i++) {
countryElement.options[countryElement.length] = new Option(country_arr[i], country_arr[i]);
if(countrySelected && country_arr[i] == countrySelected){
indexSelected = i+1;
}

}

if (stateElementId) {
if(countrySelected){
countryElement.selectedIndex = indexSelected;
populateStates(countryElementId, stateElementId);
}
countryElement.onchange = function () {
populateStates(countryElementId, stateElementId);
};
}

if(countrySelected){
countryElement.selectedIndex = indexSelected;
}
}

////////////////////THIS ENDS THE INCLUDED JAVA FILE /////////////////////
```

NOW WE LOOK AT HTML IMPLEMENTATION.

```
<!-- IS INCLUDED AT HEADER -->
<script src="inc/js/countries.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<!-- These are my select boxes -->
<select name="country" class="sm_txt_fields" id="country">
</select>

<select name="state" class="sm_txt_fields" id="state">
<script language="javascript">
populateCountries("country", "state", "Canada");
</script>
</select>
```

Code works fine, and I can preselect Canada, but i also want to pass state variable. Can't figure out how to modify code for that.

Comment: This is actually JavaScript, not Java.  Can you clarify your goal here?  What do you mean 'pass a state variable'?  When I take your code into a JS Fiddle it lets me switch countries and the states update:  https://jsfiddle.net/pnvkcbuv/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
// countries
var country_arr = new Array( "USA", "Canada", "United Kingdom");

// states
var s_a = new Array();
s_a[0]="";
s_a[1]="Alabama|Alaska|Arizona|Arkansas|California|Colorado|Connecticut|Delaware|District of Columbia|Florida|Georgia|Hawaii|Idaho|Illinois|Indiana|Iowa|Kansas|Kentucky|Louisiana|Maine|Maryland|Massachusetts|Michigan|Minnesota|Mississippi|Missouri|Montana|Nebraska|Nevada|New Hampshire|New Jersey|New Mexico|New York|North Carolina|North Dakota|Ohio|Oklahoma|Oregon|Pennsylvania|Rhode Island|South Carolina|South Dakota|Tennessee|Texas|Utah|Vermont|Virginia|Washington|West Virginia|Wisconsin|Wyoming";
s_a[2]="Alberta|British Columbia|Manitoba|New Brunswick|Newfoundland|Northwest Territories|Nova Scotia|Nunavut|Ontario|Prince Edward Island|Quebec|Saskatchewan|Yukon Territory";
s_a[3]="Barking and Dagenham|Barnet|Barnsley|Bath and North East Somerset|Bedfordshire|Bexley|Birmingham|Blackburn with Darwen|Blackpool|Bolton|Bournemouth|Bracknell Forest|Bradford|Brent|Brighton and Hove|Bromley|Buckinghamshire|Bury|Calderdale|Cambridgeshire|Camden|Cheshire|City of Bristol|City of Kingston upon Hull|City of London|Cornwall|Coventry|Croydon|Cumbria|Darlington|Derby|Derbyshire|Devon|Doncaster|Dorset|Dudley|Durham|Ealing|East Riding of Yorkshire|East Sussex|Enfield|Essex|Gateshead|Gloucestershire|Greenwich|Hackney|Halton|Hammersmith and Fulham|Hampshire|Haringey|Harrow|Hartlepool|Havering|Herefordshire|Hertfordshire|Hillingdon|Hounslow|Isle of Wight|Islington|Kensington and Chelsea|Kent|Kingston upon Thames|Kirklees|Knowsley|Lambeth|Lancashire|Leeds|Leicester|Leicestershire|Lewisham|Lincolnshire|Liverpool|Luton|Manchester|Medway|Merton|Middlesbrough|Milton Keynes|Newcastle upon Tyne|Newham|Norfolk|North East Lincolnshire|North Lincolnshire|North Somerset|North Tyneside|North Yorkshire|Northamptonshire|Northumberland|Nottingham|Nottinghamshire|Oldham|Oxfordshire|Peterborough|Plymouth|Poole|Portsmouth|Reading|Redbridge|Redcar and Cleveland|Richmond upon Thames|Rochdale|Rotherham|Rutland|Salford|Sandwell|Sefton|Sheffield|Shropshire|Slough|Solihull|Somerset|South Gloucestershire|South Tyneside|Southampton|Southend-on-Sea|Southwark|St. Helens|Staffordshire|Stockport|Stockton-on-Tees|Stoke-on-Trent|Suffolk|Sunderland|Surrey|Sutton|Swindon|Tameside|Telford and Wrekin|Thurrock|Torbay|Tower Hamlets|Trafford|Wakefield|Walsall|Waltham Forest|Wandsworth|Warrington|Warwickshire|West Berkshire|West Sussex|Westminster|Wigan|Wiltshire|Windsor and Maidenhead|Wirral|Wokingham|Wolverhampton|Worcestershire|York";


// add parameter stateSelected
function populateStates(countryElementId, stateElementId, stateSelected) {
    var indexSelected = 0;
    var selectedCountryIndex = document.getElementById(countryElementId).selectedIndex;
    var stateElement = document.getElementById(stateElementId);
    stateElement.length = 0; // Fixed by Julian Woods
    stateElement.options[0] = new Option('Select State', '0');
    stateElement.selectedIndex = 0;

    var state_arr = s_a[selectedCountryIndex].split("|");

    for (var i = 0; i < state_arr.length; i++) {
        stateElement.options[stateElement.length] = new Option(state_arr[i], state_arr[i]);
        // find state index
        if (stateSelected && state_arr[i] == stateSelected) {
            indexSelected = i + 1;
        }
    }

    // set default value if stateSelected passed
    if (stateSelected) {
        stateElement.selectedIndex = indexSelected;
    }
}

// add parameter stateSelected
function populateCountries(countryElementId, stateElementId, countrySelected, stateSelected) {
    var indexSelected = 0,
        countryElement = document.getElementById(countryElementId);

    countryElement.length = 0;
    countryElement.options[0] = new Option('Select Country', '0');
    countryElement.selectedIndex = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < country_arr.length; i++) {
        countryElement.options[countryElement.length] = new Option(country_arr[i], country_arr[i]);
        if (countrySelected && country_arr[i] == countrySelected) {
            indexSelected = i + 1;
        }

    }

    if (stateElementId) {
        if (countrySelected) {
            countryElement.selectedIndex = indexSelected;
            // call with parameter stateSelected
            populateStates(countryElementId, stateElementId, stateSelected);
        }
        countryElement.onchange = function() {
            populateStates(countryElementId, stateElementId);
        };
    }

    if (countrySelected) {
        countryElement.selectedIndex = indexSelected;
    }
}

// now you can call populateCountries with state
populateCountries("country", "state", "Canada", "Newfoundland");
```

```html
<select name="country" class="sm_txt_fields" id="country">
</select>
<select name="state" class="sm_txt_fields" id="state">
</select>
```

Comment: WOW!!!! AWESOME!!!!!! Thank you so much!!!! I have been breaking my head over this. It works beautifully! My website is up and running now :)